# How to inject Database into junit test class in Play Framework

Tags: scala, junit, playframework

I have a controller that gets a few Scala values injected into it upon creation. I need an instance of the controller in my test class, but I do not know how to insert that db:Database (which is of play.api.db.Database...a trait) during instantiation. Without it, a few of my tests are failing because this is not defined.

My controller:

```
class Messaging @Inject() (
   config: Configuration,
   db: Database)(implicit val securedActions: SecuredActions) extends Communications { ... }
```

Inside my test class setup:

```
var messagingController = new Messaging(null, null) // TEST IS FAILING BECAUSE Database is not defined here.
```

How do I replace the second `null` in the Messaging instantiation with the Database trait?

Comment: Pass a `Database`

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe get around this by either mocking out a database (with MockitoSugar) or starting an instance of one (with GuiceOneAppPerSuite):

```
class testSpec1 extends MockitoSugar {

  val database = mock[Database]
  val config = mock[Configuration]

  val controller = new Messaging(config, database)

  //etc
}


class testSpec2 extends GuiceOneAppPerSuite {

  val database = app.injector.instanceOf[Database]
  val config = app.injector.instanceOf[Configuration]

  val controller = new Messaging(config, database)
  //etc
}
```

Note that with `mock[...]`, you'll have to mock out any calls your functions would make to that class/object/whatever.